# The difference between these two icons in Outliner

Tags: interface, outliner

As in the image below:
[image]

As far as I know, both icon A and icon B mean mesh. My question is why Blender has two different icons? What's the difference?

Comment: The orange one is _Object Data_ and the green one is  _Mesh-Data_.

Comment: [Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/introduction.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To echo the commenters, the orange one means “object with mesh data,” where as the thinner triangle with dots at the corners means “mesh data.“ [Here is the manual page for a little more on the subject.](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/introduction.html) Similarly, while a curve data block is a thin line with dots at the end, an object with curve data assigned to it is shown as a thick orange line, but still in the shape of the curve data icon.